# How to play SensoryFeedback programmatically

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to use the [SensoryFeedback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/sensoryfeedback) API without having to rely on `@State` or `View.sensoryFeedback`.

I was hoping I could do something like I would in UIKit with FeedbackGenerator:

```swift
func a() {
   let feedback = SensoryFeedback(.impact)
   feedback.prepare()
   // ...
   feedback.play()
}
```

But `SensoryFeedback` only represents the *type* of feedback, it provides no functions to interact with it. And the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/sensoryfeedback) only says that you can pass it to View.sensoryFeedback to play it.